# Как передать атрибуты из html в ruby-файл?

Tags: ruby

Добрый день, уважаемое сообщество!

Я не знаю, как правильно сформулировать мой вопрос. Я тщетно пытаюсь найти ответ на свой вопрос уже несколько дней, но везде натыкаюсь на руководства по Rails. Но я не хочу использовать рельсы или какие-либо другие фреймворки. Наверняка мою задачу можно решить без их использования.

У меня есть, например, файл index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="total">
        Укажите сумму:
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="total" id="total" required="required">
      <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

И есть, например, файл main.rb:

```
require "sqlite3"

db = SQLite3::Database.open "salary.sqlite"

total = gets.chomp
db.execute "INSERT INTO salary (total) VALUES (?)", [total]
db.close

if total >= 1
  puts "Всё ОК!"
else
  puts "Что-то пошло не так..."
end
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне передать значение атрибута, заполняемого пользователем на форме в index.html, в руби-файл main.rb, чтобы он уже в свою очередь сохранил данные в базу данных?

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) вы тоже считаете за фреймворк?

Comment: Ну, да. Маленький dsl-фреймворк, разве нет?

Comment: Ну, да. Вопрос же задан не просто так, определения фреймворков по большей части настолько отфонарные, что ими можно и весь Ruby назвать. А толку от таких определений? :)

Comment: Да, есть такое дело :) В своем вопросе я хотел сказать, что хотелось бы выполнить запрос с минимум магии, чтобы понять как оно работает изнутри.

Comment: Даже у этого есть разные уровни. Хотите слушать сырой TCP-сокет и самостоятельно разбирать HTTP-заголовки? Или всё-таки вам хватит Rack, который переводит данные HTTP-запроса в структуры данных Ruby?

Comment: Скорее второе, чем первое.

Comment: Тогда ссылка во втором пункте ответа от @anoam вас должна привести к желаемому. Rack-интерфейс относительно прост в обращении. Хоть это и тоже фреймворк уровня вебсервер<>приложение :)

Comment: начал как раз изучать. спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов.

1. [**CGI**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI).

Способ особенно популярен для php. Суть метода в том, что веб-сервер (Apache или Nginx) будут просто вызывать нужный скрипт. Ответ должен быть помещён в стандартный поток вывода (puts). [Вот](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_applications.htm) статья, в которой есть пример составления cgi скриптов на руби.

Но нужно понимать, что без веб-сервера "не полетит". По настройкам веб-сервера подсказать не могу. Кроме того, процесс будет "рождаться чтобы умереть". Т.е. нужно будет позаботиться чтобы при каждом запросе всё инициализировалось заново (конфиги, подключение к бд и прочее)

2. Написать [Rack-совместимое](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131429/) приложение. И использовать rack-сервер вроде [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) или [unicorn](https://unicorn.bogomips.org/).

Это уже сложнее. Хоть и не на много - просто нужно реализовать структуру приложения, удовлетворяющую Rack-интерфейсу. Зато будет в результате будет многопоточный бэкенд сервер, который можно использовать как самостоятельно, так и совместно с веб-серверами врое Apache и Nginx (для прода рекоммендуется делать именно так).

3. Использовать родной рубёвый [**WebRick**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html).

Имхо, самый самый муторный и самый ненадёжный способ. У этого компонента специфичный интерфейс (по ссылке выше есть примеры) и он не очень хорошо зерекомендовал себя при работе с конкурирующими запросами.
Конечно, он лишён некоторых недостатков CGI, но не так эффективен, как Rack + Бэкенд сервер. К тому же, сделать Rack-интерфейс гораздо проще.

Comment: Хоть я и не получил ответа на все интересующие меня вопросы, ваш комментарий считаю очень полезным. Спасибо за помощь!